# NodeJS - using sockets and express at the same server

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, http, tcp

I am quite new at NodeJS development and networking. I've searched for a lot of similar questions here but couldn't find a straightforward solution.

I would like to create a server, that would be able to make TCP (socket) connections with GPS watches and also be able to receive HTTP requests from other sources, for example, mobile app.

Current code, that allows me to communicate with watches over socket connection (with net module):

```
const net = require('net')
const server = net.createServer()
const port = 8001

server.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('Connection opened')

    socket.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log(chunk.toString())
    })

    socket.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
})

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server running on port ' + port)
})
```

In a perfect world, I would like to use express to handle HTTP requests. I have tried (this time with http module):

```
const http = require('http')
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)
var port = 8001

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Get Request Working')
})

server.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('Connection opened')

    socket.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log(chunk.toString())
    })

    socket.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
})

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server running on port ' + port)
})
```

My get request is working perfectly, sockets are also working (I can see the connection log and data log), but when receiving data, I get a following error:

```
Connection opened
[3G*1204761865*0009*LK,0,0,90]
Error: Parse Error: Invalid method encountered
    at socketOnData (_http_server.js:563:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:323:22)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:294:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:275:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
  bytesParsed: 0,
  code: 'HPE_INVALID_METHOD',
  reason: 'Invalid method encountered',
  rawPacket: <Buffer 5b 33 47 2a 31 32 30 34 37 36 31 38 36 35 2a 30 30 30 39 2a 4c 4b 2c 30 2c 30 2c 39 30 5d>
}
```

I have tried many things, googled 2 days in a row but couldn't find a solution. Any tips or advice would be useful.

I have also tried with the socket.io library, but I guess it only works if it is implemented on the server and client-side. I can not modify the watches communication protocol.

Regards,
L

Comment: For your http server, you're probably messing it up by trying to read the raw data on the http socket.  The whole point of using an http server is that you let it handle the incoming connection and create a `request` event which you can then listen to.  That way, it does all the http protocol stuff for you and you just deal with the request URI, payload and headers.  And, if you then are using Express, you don't even handle things at that level.  I'd suggest you just remove all the `server.on('connection', ...)` code for the http server.  You are using Express for that.

Comment: FYI, in case you were wondering, it will not work well to use the exact same server for both http requests and plain TCP requests.  There are probably weird hacks where you hook in at a really low level and try to sniff whether it looks like an http connection or not by looking at the first data on the socket, but that's a hack and should generally not be done that way.  Run a plain TCP connection on a different port/server than your http connection as they are for different purposes.

Comment: FYI, you can run a webSocket server and http server on the same actual server object as the webSocket connection scheme was specifically designed to be shared with http (it actually starts its connection process with an http request and then "upgrades" to the webSocket protocol).  The webSocket server will then use the webSocket protocol to send data and you can then send arbitrary data packets either way over the webSocket connection.